# How to use MucEnterConfiguration in android smack 4.2.0-beta1?

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I want to rejoin room and don’t want any history, but **DiscussionHistory** is deprecated. So I found class **MucEnterConfiguration**. 
But I am unable to create object of **MucEnterConfiguration**.

1. **MucEnterConfiguration** is a final class so it can’t be extends and
   don’t have a public constructor.
2. **MucEnterConfiguration.Builder** is also final class so it can’t be
   extends and don’t have a public constructor.

How I can create object of it.

Thanks

Comment: Read the javadoc of MucEnterConfiguration

Comment: Sorry I can't find the Java doc, please share if any link or example

Comment: http://download.igniterealtime.org/smack/dailybuilds/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/muc/MucEnterConfiguration.html

Comment: Thanks for your precious time.

Comment: @NomanAhmedKhan are you able to find the solution?

Comment: MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(jid);            Resourcepart resourcepart = Resourcepart.from(XMPP.getInstance().connection.getUser().toString());
                        MucEnterConfiguration mucEnterConfiguration = muc.getEnterConfigurationBuilder(resourcepart).build();

Comment: Hey are you able to receive group chat?

Comment: Yes i am able to do group chat, You need to register listener for every created room. If app killed, then again register all those created group.

Comment: @NomanAhmedKhan can you have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541753/not-able-to-receive-group-message-using-smack

Answer (score 5):

```
EntityBareJid mucJid =  JidCreate.entityBareFrom(roomJid);
Resourcepart nickname = Resourcepart.from(nickname);
MultiUserChatManager manager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(connection);

MultiUserChat muc = manager.getMultiUserChat(mucJid);
MucEnterConfiguration.Builder mec = muc.getEnterConfigurationBuilder(nickname);

String lastDate = "yourLastDate";
if(lastDate!=null)
{
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parse(lastDate);
        int secondsBetween = (int) ((new Date().getTime() - date.getTime()) / 1000);
        mec.requestHistorySince(secondsBetween - 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        mec.requestNoHistory();
    }
} else {
      mec.requestNoHistory();
}
MucEnterConfiguration mucEnterConfig = mec.build();
muc.join(mucEnterConfig);
```