# Not able to receive group message using smack

Tags: android, xmpp, message, kotlin, smack

```
 var multiUserManager: MultiUserChatManager = MultiUserChatManager.getInstanceFor(constants.obj.connection)
        var multiUserChat: MultiUserChat =multiUserManager.getMultiUserChat(JidCreate.entityBareFrom(roomName))

         var a: Resourcepart = Resourcepart.from(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(applicationContext).getString("j_id", null))
         multiUserChat.join(a)

       multiUserChat.addMessageListener { object: MessageListener {
           override fun processMessage(message: Message?) {
               Log.v("Message is ",message.toString())
               Log.v("Message from ",message!!.from.toString())
               Log.v("Message is ",message.getBody())
               Log.v("Message subject ",message.getSubject())
               Log.v("Message is ",message.body)
           }

       } }
```

and I have try this also.

```
 multiUserChat.addMessageListener { GroupChatListener() }

 class GroupChatListener : StanzaListener {
    override fun processStanza(packet: Stanza?) {

        Log.v("Packet is ",packet.toString())
        Log.v("From",packet!!.from.toString())
        Log.v("Stanza id ",packet.stanzaId)
    }
```

I am not able to receive the message when anyone sent on the server but i am able to send the message.

edit:

This is the output I am getting when I press join button. I am not getting any error in the logcat.

```
 04-25 22:31:45.460 13376-13376/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/on click: fbjg
04-25 22:31:45.460 13376-13376/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/Room name: room1
04-25 22:31:45.460 13376-13376/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/Nick name: ank
04-25 22:31:45.479 13376-13376/com.example.itstym.smackchat V/Multiuser chat: MUC: room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net(user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678)
04-25 22:31:45.481 13376-16060/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/SMACK: SENT (0): <iq to='conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net' id='X2GPV-38' type='get'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'></query></iq>
04-25 22:31:45.482 13376-16060/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/SMACK: SENT (0): <r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
04-25 22:31:47.538 13376-16061/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <a h='15' xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><iq xml:lang='en' to='user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678' from='conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net' type='result' id='X2GPV-38'><query xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'><identity name='Chatrooms' type='text' category='conference'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#info'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/disco#items'/><feature var='jabber:iq:register'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/><feature var='vcard-temp'/><feature var='urn:xmpp:mucsub:0'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#unique'/><feature var='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'/><feature var='urn:xmpp:mam:tmp'/><feature var='urn:xmpp:mam:0'/><feature var='urn:xmpp:mam:1'/><x type='result' xmlns='jabber:x:data'><field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'><value>http://jabber.org/network/serverinfo</value></field></x></query></iq><r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
04-25 22:31:47.541 13376-16060/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/SMACK: SENT (0): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='16'/><presence to='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net/ank' id='X2GPV-37'><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'></x><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='os2Kusj3WEOivn5n4iFr/ZEO8ls='/></presence>
04-25 22:31:47.823 13376-16061/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <presence xml:lang='en' to='user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678' from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net/an' id='Kd5p0-48'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='os2Kusj3WEOivn5n4iFr/ZEO8ls='/><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'><item role='participant' affiliation='none'/></x></presence>
04-25 22:31:47.835 13376-16061/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/><presence xml:lang='en' to='user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678' from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net/ank' id='X2GPV-37'><c xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/caps' hash='sha-1' node='http://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/smack' ver='os2Kusj3WEOivn5n4iFr/ZEO8ls='/><x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc#user'><item jid='user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678' role='participant' affiliation='none'/><status code='110'/></x></presence><message xml:lang='en' to='user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678' from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net/user1' type='groupchat' id='54f75761-b5cd-4955-8d32-5609e89a2417'><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><composing/></x><delay from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net' stamp='2017-04-21T11:52:40.966514Z' xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay'/><body>hey</body></message><message xml:lang='en' to='user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678' from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net/user1' type='groupchat' id='1492776073223:msg'><active xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/chatstates'/><delay from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net' stamp='2017-04-21T12:01:13.896472Z' xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay'/><body>asd&apos;</body></message>
04-25 22:31:47.835 13376-16060/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/SMACK: SENT (0): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='17'/>
04-25 22:31:47.836 13376-13376/com.example.itstym.smackchat V/Joined response: kotlin.Unit
04-25 22:31:47.836 13376-13376/com.example.itstym.smackchat V/Joined: true
04-25 22:31:47.836 13376-13376/com.example.itstym.smackchat I/Choreographer: Skipped 142 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-25 22:31:47.841 13376-16061/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <message xml:lang='en' to='user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678' from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net/ankur' type='groupchat' id='05333f72-0ffc-49ba-8180-23c3b00b5d31'><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><composing/></x><delay from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net' stamp='2017-04-24T11:02:35.386083Z' xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay'/><body>jfdgsdk</body></message><message xml:lang='en' to='user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678' from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net/wefa' type='groupchat' id='e0e5cf9a-a363-4f05-a8cf-b2d1016a99d2'><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><composing/></x><delay from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net' stamp='2017-04-24T11:25:57.859462Z' xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay'/><body>dgdfgsdfgsg</body></message><message xml:lang='en' to='user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678' from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net/abv' type='groupchat' id='fr3u8-51'><delay from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net' stamp='2017-04-24T11:28:05.832722Z' xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay'/><body>hi</body></message><message xml:lang='en' to='user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678' from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net/wefa' type='groupchat' id='6259ccab-5235-4367-8b57-f03f27ec8c9a'><x xmlns='jabber:x:event'><composing/></x><delay from='room1@conference.replica3377
04-25 22:31:47.873 13376-16061/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/SMACK: RECV (0): .cloudapp.net' stamp='2017-04-24T11:28:24.801581Z' xmlns='urn:xmpp:delay'/><body>welcome abv</body></message><message to='user1@replica3377.cloudapp.net/1540794269789260263741678' from='room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net' type='groupchat'><subject/></message>
04-25 22:31:47.881 13376-16096/com.example.itstym.smackchat W/MultiUserChat: Message subject not changed by a full JID: room1@conference.replica3377.cloudapp.net
04-25 22:31:48.030 13376-16061/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/SMACK: RECV (0): <r xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3'/>
04-25 22:31:48.031 13376-16060/com.example.itstym.smackchat D/SMACK: SENT (0): <a xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3' h='25'/>
```

**edit 2:**

```
multiUserChat?.addMessageListener {
                    Log.v("listener","yup")
                    MessageListener { message ->
                        Log.v("Message is complete ",message.toString())
                        Log.v("Message from ",message?.from.toString())
                        Log.v("Message is body",message?.getBody())
                        Log.v("Message subject ",message?.getSubject())
                        Log.v("Message body ",message?.body)
                    }
                }
```

Whenever someone send me the message                         Log.v("listener","yup") called. But don't go inside messagelistener. 
I have read the log output and find them I am getting the msg in the form of xml.

Comment: Have you try to join room every time after successful login.

Comment: yes. After login i calling multiUserChat.join(a)
 @Malik

Comment: and what are the response of joining?

Comment: what is the means of joining here @Farhan? Can you clarify it?

Comment: @Farhan multiUserChat.join(a) returns kotlin.unit

Comment: when u join a room, your client should receive some packets as a response from server. Check those. If there is any error or u don't understand them. paste here. start your app in debug mode. and check all the logs.

Comment: @Farhan I have added the log that i am getting when calling join.

Comment: @Farhan I checked the log. and find that I am getting the message in XML format. How will I show this log output to the user?

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal Did you find the solution?

Comment: nops@AndroidStorm

Comment: See my post that will help you I think.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45387934/7346129

Answer (score 1):

What I did:

First Join in to the GroupChat, then create a custom listener to get the missed messages and on the onSuccess add the messageListener. That is provide me the history messages in a List<> and after that the app start listen the new Message coming from this GroupChat.

```
public void joinToGroupChat(final MultiUserChat multiUserChat, final OpenFireListener<List<Message>> listener) {

    if (!multiUserChat.isJoined()) {
       multiUserChat.join(connection.getUser().getResourcepart());
    }

    getPendingMessages(multiUserChat, new OpenFireListener<List<Message>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Message> result) {
            multiUserChat.addMessageListener(messageListener);
            listener.onSuccess(result);
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String message) {
            listener.onError(message);
        }
    });
}

private MessageListener messageListener = new MessageListener() {
    @Override
    public void processMessage(Message message) {
        //I only use the subject and body in my project
        listener.notifyMessage(message.getSubject(), message.getBody());
    }
};
```

Make sure that you are joined into the GroupChat in the same context and implemented your custom listener. This is my generic implementation.

```
public interface OpenFireListener<T>{
    void onSuccess(T result);
    void onError(String message);
}

public interface OpenFireServerListener {
    enum STATE {ERROR, CONNECTION_CLOSED, RECONNECTION_SUCCESS, RECONNECTION_FAILED, AUTHENTICATED, NOT_AUTHORIZED, CONNECTED}

    void notifyStatusOpenFireServer(STATE state, String message);
    void notifyMessage(String streamName, String streamId);

}
```