# How to (if possible) get the OpenFire GroupChat History without joined (SmackAPI)

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire, smack

What I'm doing now is:

1- Retrieving all GroupChat

```
        List<HostedRoom> rooms = multiUserChatManager.getHostedRooms(groupChatService.asDomainBareJid());
        for (HostedRoom room :
                rooms) {
            if (room.getJid().getLocalpart().equals(groupChatRoomId)){
                multiUserChat = multiUserChatManager.getMultiUserChat(room.getJid());
            }
        }
```

2- Join in the GroupChat

```
       if (multiUserChat != null) {
            if (!multiUserChat.isJoined()) {
                multiUserChat.join(connection.getUser().getResourcepart());
            }
        }
```

3- Getting all messages

```
  public List<Message> getOldMessages() {
    List<Message> oldMessages = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        Message message = multiUserChat.nextMessage();

        while (message != null) {
            oldMessages.add(message);
            message = multiUserChat.nextMessage();
        }
    } catch (MultiUserChatException.MucNotJoinedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    multiUserChat.addMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
        @Override
        public void processMessage(final Message message) {
            listener.notifyMessage(message.getSubject(), message.getBody());

        }
    });
    return oldMessages;
}
```

I need to do the same without joined and show my presence for all users into the GroupChat.

***In other words my app show you the GroupChat that you previous joined and I want to implement the missed messages notification for all GroupChat in a list.***

Comment: So what i understand from your question is: You don't want to perform XMPP Login and Set Presence as "Available" but want to fetch group chat messages?

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal this is part of my code sorry this is not related with the issue.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal my app show the user the list of GroupChats that you joined previously so I want to show the missed messages that you have.

Comment: I hope you are already aware of XMPP Multi User Chat (XEP-0045), When a user goes offline, it's no more considered part of that room. So in this case, there are no offline group chat messages.

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal yes my current solution is that join in to the GroupChat and retrieve all history messages, the question is that if there is a solution to get the history message without join in every GroupChat

Comment: No if you don't write a custom plugin by yourself. XMPP specs require to join a groupchat to access to relative history messages.

Comment: @AndroidStorm can you show msg listener code. because I am also facing issue while receiving  the group message.

Comment: @MrPk I'm in your way, but maybe someone in this community can suggest better way to solve that. Thank you.

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal this listener is an interface that I create and implement on my presenter. What issue are you receiving? Do you have the question created, maybe I can answer you through it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43541753/7124362 please check here @Android Strom

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal i posted my solution I hope it help you.

Comment: @AnkurKhandelwal friend did you check your question? I already answered you.